# jq - filtering JSON by searching key values

Tags: json, jq

Data sample - shodan_data.json (full sample: https://pastebin.com/KFkVmc2M)

```
{
      "ip": 3301234701,
      "_shodan": {
        "options": {
          "referrer": "7ae15507-f5cc-4353-b72e-5cc0b1c34c5e"
        },
      },
      "hash": -1056085507,
      "os": null,
      "title": "WHM Login",
      "opts": {
        "vulns": ["!CVE-2014-0160"],
        "heartbleed": "2017/08/29 09:57:30 196.196.216.13:2087 - SAFE\
        }
      },
      "isp": "Fiber Grid Inc",
      "http": {
        "redirects": [],
        "title": "WHM Login",
        "robots": null,
        "favicon": null,
        "host": "196.196.216.13",
        "html":
}
```

My `jq` code:

```
jq -r 'select((.opts.vulns[0] | contains("!CVE-2014-0160")))? | ['.ip_str', '.isp', '.timestamp', .opts.vulns[0]] | @csv' shodan_data.json
```

Example output when using full dataset:

```
"165.231.171.237","Fiber Grid Inc","2017-08-22T02:24:07.658547","!CVE-2014-0160"
```

Right now what it does is that it's searching for a specific JSON object `.opts.vulns[0]` with a value `!CVE-2014-0160` then filters the entire object where the value was found and prints the object values specified `.ip_str', '.isp', '.timestamp', .opts.vulns[0]` as csv. Also suppresses any errors where the searchable value isn't found which allows me to write the output to a .csv file.

What I would like it to do is to take whatever value I would like to find, like in the example `!CVE-2014-0160` (like a search engine) and be able to recursively go through the entire JSON dataset and have the same end result as my code atm.

I've been trying to figure this one out and have been trying out `..` recursive descent and other methods but the way I'm filtering the data seems to indicate that what I'm trying to accomplish might need a different approach if even possible?

Answer (score 1):

First, rest assured that if you can formulate the requirements a bit more precisely, jq will be up to the task.

In fact, the following, which is just a small variation of what you already have, should meet the requirements as I currently understand them:

```
..
| ((.opts.vulns | index("!CVE-2014-0160"))? // empty) as $ix
| [.ip_str, .isp, .timestamp, .opts.vulns[$ix]]
| @csv
```

With the pastebin data, this produces:

```
"196.196.216.13","Fiber Grid Inc","2017-08-29T06:57:22.546423","!CVE-2014-0160"
```

(I have included the computation of $ix in case you want a more complex matching criterion.)

#### Parameterization

If you want to parameterize the string to search for, replace it by (for example) `$string` in the jq program, and invoke jq like so

```
jq -r --arg string "!CVE-2014-0160" ......
```

For example:

```
jq -r --arg string "!CVE-2014-0160" -f program.jq shodan_data.json
```

#### Being agnostic about the location of the string of interest within the .isp object

```
jq -r —arg string "!CVE-2014-0160" '..|select(.isp?)|. as $x
  | select(..==$string)|$x|[.ip,.ip_str]|@csv’ data.json
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what your code does compared to mine? My idea was that the end-user wouldn't have to know anything about the JSON (like where the data is or if it's even in there) that is being parsed and could use the "program" as a search engine. Forgetting  `!CVE-2014-0160`, I could replace it with anything and if it's found in the data then the output will be produced, like in the example (I do understand I can't just print everything if I want to write it to csv).

Comment: maybe illustrates my idea better: `jq -r 'select(( **code that looks through the entire data** contains("**enter here what you want to search for**")))? | ['.ip_str', '.isp', '.timestamp'] | @csv' shodan_data.json`

Comment: 1.) The .. causes the program to look throughout the JSON document. 2.) Please see my update regarding parameterization.

Comment: thanks for the code examples, they will come in handy but the core problem still persists. That is `.opts.vulns` in the program.jq. I want to assume that the user who is using the program has no knowledge of the JSON data and the searchable info can be anywhere not in any specific JSON object. Simply put, can't I just replace `.opts.vulns` with `..` or completely ignore it and just deal with what we want to find and not where to find it?

Comment: @user3086917 - I'm afraid your goal is very unclear to the point of appearing muddled.  I would suggest you ask another SO question, making clear what exactly is being matched (and whether the match should be based on string equality, or some other criterion), where the match can occur (in key names?), and what is supposed to be done once a match has been found.  In your new question, please adhere to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - especially the MINIMAL part.

Comment: I'll try once more here. This "...match should be based on string equality..." I think explains best what I want to do. Given a `string` or `valid JSON key value` try to match it with all the key values the program can find in the dataset and then just print out the object where that value belonged to..

Comment: @user3086917 - see update. If that isn’t close to what you want, please ask a new SO Q following the mcve guidelines.